# SQL 2005 fetching data for current year

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a view that holds sales data from 2012 till date, I need to write the query that show me only current year sales (2013).

This is what I tried in the first stage

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Sales_Data] 
WHERE invoiceDate  between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31'
```

this query takes 2 sec to load the data,I though to change the query to fetch data that not required me to update it manually and this is what I found on the Net:

```
select * from [Sales_Data]  
where datepart(yyyy,invoiceDate) =datepart(yyyy,getdate()) 
and datepart(yyyy,invoiceDate) =datepart(yyyy,getdate())
```

As a result this query takes much longer to show the data (9 sec). 
Please let me know if there is a better query to define and get data in less time ?

Comment: Your second query repeats the same condition in the `WHERE` clause for absolutely no reason. It can be shortened to `SELECT * FROM [Sales_Data]  WHERE DatePart(yyyy, invoiceDate) = DatePart(yyyy, GetDate())`

Answer (score 2):

Your second query requires sql server to perform a calculation for each row you are querying against.

The following query more closely matches your original select statement.

```
select * from [Sales_data]
where invoiceDate between DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0) --- First Day of current year
and DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -3,DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)) --- Last Day of current year
```

Depending on what is going on with the view you are querying against, you may also benefit from having an index which includes the invoiceDate field.

You may want to check the execution plan generated when you run your query to see what is going on behind the scenes when the query runs.

Comment: my friend, Your query takes 41 seconds to execute :) please let me know how I can add an index. Thanks

Comment: You might have something else going on here as my query should take only a few milliseconds longer than your first query as the only real difference is it is calculating the start and end dates for the between statement. How does these perform if you do `select count(*) from...` instead of `select * from...` ? For creating indexes in Sql 2005 there is a good tuturial on code project at: [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39006/Overview-of-SQL-Server-2005-2008-Table-Indexing-Pa](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39006/Overview-of-SQL-Server-2005-2008-Table-Indexing-Pa)

Comment: I can't see any problem, Ihave test the same query in different server also but your version takes longer than all other queries.

Comment: I apologize if I sent you down the wrong path. I have used queries like this many times, usually in the form of a similar query that returns data for just the current month, and never noticed performance issues with them. Before I posted my answer I tested the query against a database we maintain (a logging table with 146mm records in it, 4.4mm from this year) and my query performed on par with your first query and 2 seconds faster than your second query.